# Странное поведение заголовочных файлов в C++

Tags: c++, header

Вообщем, я пытался запихнуть все заголовки в один файл, что бы не получать ошибки от линкера.
Но, я столкнулся с проблемой:
Оба Hooks.h и Visuals.h были включены в один и тот же файл, 
Hooks.h не имеет ошибок. Ни со стороны компилятора, ни с интеллисенса.

```cpp
    #pragma once

    namespace Hooks {
        // VMTHook, Включенный в родительском файле, здесь есть.
        // Более того, IDirect3DDevice тоже здесь есть, тоже самое и с HRESULT.

        VMTHook D3DDeviceHooks;
        VMTHook CHLClientHooks;
        VMTHook ClientModeHooks;

        /**
        *  Setups all the hooks.
        */
        void SetupHooks() {
            D3DDeviceHooks = VMTHook(g_pD3ddevice);
            CHLClientHooks = VMTHook(g_pClient);
            ClientModeHooks = VMTHook(g_pClientmode);

            Visuals::Hooks::orgEndScene = (Visuals::Hooks::EndSceneFn)D3DDeviceHooks.HookFunction(42, Visuals::Hooks::hookEndScene);
        }
    }
```

Однако, в Visuals.h начинаются проблемы.
Включения, которые я сделал в родительском заголовке, на этот файл не распостраняются.
Сам компилятор дает мне отчет о том, что в файле ошибки. Какие - смотрите в коде.

```cpp
    #pragma once

    namespace Visuals {
        namespace Hooks {
            typedef HRESULT(__stdcall* EndSceneFn)(IDirect3DDevice9*); 
            // IDirect3DDevice9 не определен, HRESULT тоже

            EndSceneFn orgEndScene = nullptr;

            HRESULT __stdcall hookEndScene(IDirect3DDevice9* device)
            {
                if (!Visuals::Initialized)
                    Visuals::Initialize(device);

                Visuals::Draw(g_pGlobalvars->frametime);

                return orgEndScene(device);
            }

            WNDPROC orgWndProc = 0;
            // WNDPROC не определен

            LRESULT __stdcall hookWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
                if ((msg == WM_KEYDOWN || msg == WM_KEYUP) && (wParam == Visuals::Menu::Variables::MenuHotkey)) {
                    Visuals::Menu::Open();
                }

                return CallWindowProcA(orgWndProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        ...
```

Вот файл, в который они включены:

```
    ... // Здесь много включений, таких как "windows" и "d3d9"

    #include "sdk/Definitions.h"

    #include "Utils/PatternScans.h"

    #include "Visuals.h"
    #include "Menu.h"

    #include "VMTHook.h"
    #include "Hooks.h"
```

Вы, возможно, можете испытать ту же проблему у себя, повторив эти действия:

- Создайте простой проект Visual Studio 2017 (MSVC Компилятор)
- Создайте заголовочный файл, создайте еще 2
- Включите оба созданных вами файла в первый

```
    #include "header1.h"
    #include "header2.h"
```

- В этот же файл добавьте пару включений, по типу "stdio"

```
    #include "stdio.h"

    #include "header1.h"
    #include "header2.h"
```

- Проверьте наличие каких либо недостающих определений из stdio в этих файлах.

```
    // Header 1
    void Func1(){
        printf("abc1\n"); 
    }

    // Header 2
    void Func2(){
        printf("abc2\n"); 
    }
```

Comment: во-первых, линкер не должен ругаться на хидера - он работает с библиотеками, работа с хидерами - ответственность препроцессора.Во-вторых, хидер должен сам по себе включать всю необходимую для него информацию, а не рассчитывать что потом кто-то выше включет перед ним нужный хидер - это ужасный подход! Мало того, что он требует знания того, что нужно еще подключить для использования хидера, так еще стоит отформатировать код и он становится неработоспособным!

Comment: К тому же зачем вам реализация нешаблонных функций в хидерах? Вынесете ее в `cpp` фалы, а в хидерах используйте предекларацию

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch линкер жаловался на .obj файлы, из за того, что в каком то другом файле уже есть определение какой то функции.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch несмотря на то, что это плохой подход, я должен так сделать, что бы избежать ошибок линкера. Так, как я не могу два раза включить кое какой заголовочный файл, мне остается надеяться на наследственность.

Comment: я извиняюсь, но насколько хорошо вы знаете C/C++? Вы понимаете, как устроена компиляция? Вы понимаете чем различаются cpp и хидера? Вы знаете что компиляция состоит из нескольких стадий, вроде: препоцессинг, трансляция, линковка и т.д.? Судя по тому, что вы написали выше - все ответы отрицательны. Линкер ругается как-раз таки из-за того, что вы в хидере реализовали ваши функции (смотрите препроцессинг и компиляцию). При этом вы не задумывались зачем вы используете `pragma once`? Это исключает включения хидера дважды! Так что вам не стоит беспокоится об этом

Comment: Извините, но вам тоже нужно понимать, что я не дурак, и не сделал бы так с пустого места.

Comment: я ни в коем случае не называю вас дураком (несмотря на ваши заявления) но во-первых: разделение хидеров и cpp файлов это абсолютно стандартная практика и при прямых руках она не может приводить к ошибкам, во-вторых: вы не можете вот так брать и реализовывать нешаблонные функции в хидерах - это будет приводить к ошибкам (о чем я выше и писал). Если уж реализуете функции в хидерах, то хотя бы отмечайте их как inline. PS не следует писать подобных пассажей - это говорит не в вашу пользу